# The specified @job_id does not exist

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

After deleting a SQL Server Agent job I continue to get notifications that the job attempted to run and failed. I am receiving the following error message.

> [000] Unable to retrieve steps for job my_job
>   [298] SQLServer Error: 14262, The specified @job_id
>   ('CC65FEFB-0033-442E-B55E-6209E25C5039') does not exist. [SQLSTATE
>   42000]

I have checked the following tables in the msdb database and none of them have the specified job_id except the dbo.sysjobhistory table.

- dbo.sysjobs
- dbo.sysjobschedules
- dbo.sysjobsteps
- dbo.sysjobstepslogs
- dbo.sysjobservers
- dbo.sysjobactivity
- dbo.sysjobhistory

Is there anywhere else I can look?
Also, today I have stopped and restarted the SQL Server Agent and will update this post tomorrow with the result.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Start a trace for calls to sp_start_job - you should catch the offender pretty quickly.

Comment: Additional information being requested on twitter so I thought I would add it here.  Q: "anything in codebase/schedule task calling sp_start_job?" A: No

Comment: @AaronBertrand I will set that up tonight! Thanks.

Comment: How about `sp_delete_job @job_id =` ? Also, any replication involved ?

Comment: Additional information being requested on twitter. Q:"what build of SQL Server?" A:"SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 (10.50.2425)"

Comment: @Kin how would deleting the job (which has already happened) stop the notifications for trying to run a job that has been deleted?

Comment: @Kin no, no replication involved. It is an old maintenance script that was being replaced.

Comment: @kenwilsondba Aaron's suggestion of a quick trace would help to find out the offender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A stop and start of the SQL Agent fixed the issue.